# Can I create a tile in Windows 8 that starts Chrome with a certain website?

Tags: windows-8

I'm not trying to create any apps or anything, I was just wondering if it would be possible to create a tile that would open up Google Chrome, then hyperlink to a website? Like if I wanted to reference the JavaDocs, it would take me straight to them.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shortcut to chrome.exe which references a url so when the shortcut is opened, it automatically opens whatever site you want.

First, create a shortcut to the page you want to pin in Chrome. Right click anywhere in the desktop side and select New > Shortcut.

You'll get a dialog box like this one.

[image]

In the dialog box, type:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
```

(replace the url with whatever site you want)

Click next.

Name the new shortcut Java Docs (or whatever you want).

[image]

You should now see a new shortcut which, if opened, will go straight to java docs in Chrome.

You can pin this to the modern UI by right-clicking the shortcut and selecting "Pin to start". It will look something like this when you're done:

[image]

This will work regardless of which browser is your default so you could use this to open specific pages in Chrome if, for example, they are not IE10 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The above described method is certainly a reasonable way of doing it, although there is a better way.

If you use Oblytile ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865 ) you can insert any web link by typing the URL in the box labeled as program path.

There are many advantages of this method. You get a much better looking start screen, it is much quicker to make the tiles this way and  there is an excellent tile manager shown by clicking the folder icon in the top right corner where you can view, edit and remove your tiles for links.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create a tile and hyperlink to a website. You can achieve this by using the native IE10 browser by implementing navigation schemas in the page load event of the app. Microsoft certification requirement doesn't seem to deny an hyperlinked tiled app. Let's check it though